# Every open subset of the real line can be expressed uniquely as a countable union of disjoint open intervals (Pugh Theorem 9, chapter 2)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

In Real mathematical analysis by Pugh, Theorem 9 of chapter 2 is:

> Every open set $\mathbb{U} \subset \mathbb{R}$ can be uniquely expressed as a countable union of disjoint open intervals. The endpoints of the intervals do not belong to $\mathbb{U}$.

I am not getting this theorem. Please explain through example.

Comment: You have 150 characters to use for the title. Please use that to make it as descriptive as possible. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144) for more advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $U$ is open, we can select any point $x_1 \in U$, and we are guaranteed an open interval $I_1 = (x_1\!-\!n, \ x_1\!+\!m)$ such that $I_1 \subset U$.  Choose $n$ and $m$ to be as large as possible while still having $I_1 \subset U$.  Note that it is possible to have $n = \infty$ or $m = \infty$, as would happen with $U = (-\infty, a)$ or $(a, \infty)$ or even just $\mathbb{R}$ itself.

If every point of $U$ is contained in $I_1$, then we are done.  Otherwise, choose a point $x_2 \in U \setminus I_1$ and repeat the above.  Do this repeatedly until we have $\displaystyle \bigcup_k I_k = U$.

All that remains is to check that, if the set of intervals $\{I_k \}$ is infinite, then it is only countably infinite.  Recall that [every interval contains a rational number](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Rationals_are_Everywhere_Dense_in_Reals) and that $\mathbb{Q}$ [is countable](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Rational_Numbers_are_Countably_Infinite).

---

**Example$^\dagger$**:  Suppose $U = (0,5) \cup (7,10)$, and suppose we choose $x_1 = 2$.  The largest $n$ and $m$ such that $(2\!-\!n, \ 2\!+\!m) \subset U$ are $n = 2$ and $m=3$.  But notice $I_1 = (2\!-\!2, \ 2\!+\!3) \subsetneq U$.  So we choose a point $x_2 \in U \setminus I_1$, say $x_2 = 8$.  The maximum $n$ and $m$ possible so that $I_2 = (8\!-\!n, \ 8\!+\!m) \subset U$ are $n = 1$ and $m = 2$.  Because $I_1 \cup I_2$ accounts for all the points of $U$, we are done.

$\dagger$ Yeah, the example is kind of silly because it's *already* written as a union of disjoint open intervals, and we're just recovering already-known information.  Alas, this is unavoidable since *all possible examples* will be of that form.  Hopefully it's a good concrete illustration nevertheless.

Comment: Very simple and clear explanation. +1

Comment: If $\mathbb{I_1}$ can't cover whole $\mathbb{U}$ then how these $\mathbb{I_1}$ and $\mathbb{I_2}$ are disjoint ?

Comment: @MeetR, you are choosing $I_k$ to be the "largest" interval so that $I_k \subset U$; this ensures that $I_k$ is bounded by points not in $U$.  It is possible that $n = \infty$ and $m = -\infty$.

Comment: Oops, I meant to write $m= \infty$ as well.